# V3.34 fitbound shows additional clusters on map reposition

Tags: google-maps-api-3

We are experiencing similar issue as described by the fiddler below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmm5hrp9/2/

```
var map;
var markers;
var markerCluster;
var markersAmount;
var gridSize;
var minimumClusterSize;
var t0, t1;

function initialize() {

    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    
    createMarkers();
}

function createMarkers() {

    // Define the number of random markers to create
    markersAmount = isNaN(document.getElementById('markersAmount').value) ? 5000 : document.getElementById('markersAmount').value;

    // Define the marker cluster grid size
    gridSize = isNaN(document.getElementById('gridSize').value) ? 100 : document.getElementById('gridSize').value;

    // Define the marker cluster minimum cluser size
    minimumClusterSize = isNaN(document.getElementById('minimumClusterSize').value) ? 10 : document.getElementById('minimumClusterSize').value;

    // Empty markers array
    markers = [];
    // Cluster all the markers

    // Define the max latitude on a mercator projection
    var maxLat = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI)) * 180 / Math.PI;

    // Loop and create the markers
    for (var i = 0; i < markersAmount; i++) {

        // Calculate a random lat and lng
        var lat = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxLat * 2)) - maxLat;
        var lng = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360) - 180;

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
        });

        markers.push(marker);
    }
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
      imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m',
      gridSize: parseInt(gridSize),
      minimumClusterSize: parseInt(minimumClusterSize)
    });
    
}

function fitBounds() {

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        markers.forEach(m => bounds.extend(m.getPosition()));
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('fitBounds'), 'click', fitBounds);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This worked fine in v3.31 without any issues however that version is deprecated now.

We also see that the fitbounds is used in markercluster as well. Do we need to make changes in this as well?

What would be an alternative that can be used to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ive had issues with google maps using the clustering from the v3 utility library since v3.32. Im pretty sure there are some code changes that need to be made to it, but not sure its being actively maintained.